# What Indy FTP Event To Use To Detect Connection Closed Gracefully

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy, delphi-xe7

When using Indy TIDFTP what event should be used to detect that the connection has been closed gracefully?  If the connection is closed what are the proper calls to make to reset TIDFTP so that the user can log back in?

I have tried using the IdFTP1Status event but even though the connection is lost when the app is idle for 15 minutes the event does not execute.  I place a break point in the event but the break point is never reached and the code in the event is not executed.  The variable ALoggedIn is true during the test.

Other posts on this subject suggest that IDFTP should be reset with:

```
IdFTP1.Disconnect(False);
IdFTP1.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
```

Here is the events code:

```
procedure TForm1.IdFTP1Status(ASender: TObject; const AStatus: TIdStatus;
  const AStatusText: string);
{ Show the FTP server response to commands in the statusbar and detect disconnected. }
begin
  { If LoggedIn and connection is disconnected then logout and enable login }
  if (ALoggedIn) and (AStatus = hsDisconnected) then
  begin
    StatusBar1.SimplePanel := True;
    StatusBar1.SimpleText := 'FTP connection lost.  Please login again.';
    StatusBar1.Update;
    TaskMessageDlg('Connection Error',
      'FTP connection lost.  Please login again.', mtError, [mbOk], 0);
    IdFTP1.Disconnect(False);
    IdFTP1.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
  end
  else
  begin
    StatusBar1.SimplePanel := True;
    StatusBar1.SimpleText := AStatusText;
    StatusBar1.Update;
  end;
end;
```

Also, because it takes 15 minutes for the connection to be lost is there someway to simulate a "Connection Closed Gracefully" so that debugging can be speeded up as I have to log in then wait 15 minutes for the connection to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most part, Indy clients are not event driven (with a few exceptions to that rule, like `TIdTelnet` and `TIdCmdTCPClient`). You tell Indy to do something, it does that something, and does not return until finished.  If something goes wrong, an exception is raised.

There is no event when a client loses its connection to the server.  When the socket is closed, an exception will be raised (such as `EIdConnClosedGracefully`) the next time you try to access the socket.  You will have to catch that exception in a `try/except` block.  You can then `Disconnect()` and re-`Connect()` as needed.

It is your app's responsibility to not sit idle for 15 minutes.  If the user is not interacting with your app for that long, but you still need to keep the connection alive, your app can use a timer to periodically send `NOOP`s to the server, like a heartbeat.

Comment: Where would you put the try/except block? Send a command in a timer say every 10 seconds with a try/except block?

Comment: Yes.  Wrap each section of TIdFTP code in a try/except.